# Testing private @IBOutlets and @IBActions

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

We can make `@IBOutlets` and `@IBAction` private. 
Example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction private func nextTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

We haven't access to this properties and methods outside class, which is good I thing.

But what about testing class with private outlets and actions? Are there any ways to test private outlet or method in XCTestCase, or I have to just expose them outside class making internal?

For purpose of test `@IBOutlet`s/`@IBAction`s should be internally visible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Unit testing private variables and methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421235/swift-unit-testing-private-variables-and-methods)

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to test `private` methods with `XCTest`.

That's because Swift's `private` is really private and the compiler uses this information to make better optimizations of your code.

To test a method it either must be `public` or `internal` and you can import your module with `@testable`.

Excerpt from [Should I test private methods or only public ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones) :

> I do not unit test private methods. A private method is an implementation detail that should be hidden to the users of the class. Testing private methods breaks encapsulation.

Comment: But private method are not out off bugs spells.

Answer (score 0):

Use private(set) for the IBOutlets.
So you can read it outside the class but cannot modify it.

Answer (score -1):

Private methods MUST be tested also, but *the point is not change anything in the class under test for running the tests*.

By default you can access to IBOutlets from unit tests, but in case you have set them as private you can always create a new MockSubclass of your class under test and then expose the private stuff.

During the test just instantiate your mock subclass and call a function that returns your private outlet.

Look out! keep your mock classes always under test target.

Comment: Could you share an example with IBAction and IBOutlet?