# How do you unit test internal methods of a CocoaPod Library?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a private iOS Library that I want to use CocoaPods to manage. However, I can't wrap my head around how to unit test the internal methods of the library. I used `pod lib create` to set up my file structure, and this creates Tests that point to the 'Example' project, and therefore only have access to methods from my library that I expose as 'Open'. How can I unit test the internal methods that are not 'Open'? Obviously any Test Target I create under the Source Files gets erased once I do `pod install`...Why doesn't `pod lib create` make it easier to actually test your source code instead of just its exposed functionality?

This github issue addresses my exact problem, but I still don't quite understand the resolution: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4755

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I think i figured out what I was struggling with. By using the @testable import of the pod module I am able to test 'Public' methods. Initially I thought I had to make them 'Open' but the keyword @testable solves this for me.

Comment: Basically, [you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105021/3141234).

Comment: Why would you want to test someone else's code? If you don't trust the library, then don't use it. Good libraries are well tested.

Comment: You should test everything within the private library itself not from the consumer of the library (the app using cocoapods to manage the library)

Comment: @Paul.s Sorry maybe this isn't worded clearly, I am creating a CocoaPod Library myself and I want to test the source code that I am writing

Comment: @Cristik I am trying to test the source code of the library I am writing, not some else's code.

Comment: @AndyMeagher my original comment stands. If you write `FrameworkA` that you then import into you `App`. You should test `FrameworkA`'s code from within `FrameworkA` not the `App`.

Comment: @AndyMeagher you don't need to test non-public stuff, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421807/1974224) from more details

Answer (score 1):

for reference, the solution is:
use `@testable import`

check out:
https://medium.com/practical-ios-development/how-to-write-unit-tests-in-swift-without-making-everything-public-ae218acc4ec4